# error 1067: Invalid implicit coercion as class?

Tags: actionscript-3, implicit, coercion

I have a piece of code creating an instance of an object I call Line.

```
var velLine:Line;
if(/*some conditions*/)
    velLine = new Line(0, 0, x, y);
```

x and y are taken from an object in the program that represents a player (it's supposed to be a video game).  They are of type Number.

The third line shown is throwing the error:
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Line to an unrelated type Class

Any idea what's causing this? BTW, the parameters for the Line constructor are all of type Number

EDIT: Some more code, hope this helps

```
//point for the center of the player
            var pCenter:Point = new Point(p.x + 38, p.y + 38);

            //First bounds check the endpoints
            //If you're hitting an endpoint, bounce off like it's a circle
            //return false in this case so that the program doesn't trigger 2 simultaneous collisions
            var velLine:Line, perpenLine:Line;
            if(distBetweenPoints(pCenter, new Point(l.x1, l.y1))){
                velLine:Line = new Line(0, 0, p.velVector.x, p.velVector.y);
                perpenLine:Line = new Line(l.x1 - 10, l.y1 - (-1 / velLine.m) * 10, l.x1 + 10, l.y1 + (-1 / velLine.m) * 10);
                operateCollision(p, perpenLine);
                trace("hit an end point");
                return false;
            }else if(distBetweenPoints(pCenter, new Point(l.x2, l.y2))){
                velLine:Line = new Line(0, 0, p.velVector.x, p.velVector.y);
                perpenLine:Line = new Line(l.x2 - 10, l.y2 - (-1 / velLine.m) * 10, l.x2 + 10, l.y2 + (-1 / velLine.m) * 10);
                operateCollision(p, perpenLine);
                trace("hit an end point");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: http://curtismorley.com/2008/05/28/actionscript-error-1067-implicit-coercion-of-a-value-of-type-void-to-an-unrelated-type-function/

Comment: How does this error apply to something being a class?

Comment: If you don't have the conditional in there, what happens? Can you provide more contextual code. I don't see enough there to even try to guess.

Comment: I'm amazed this compiles. Your variable assignments are syntactically incorrect, type definitions should only be given when declaring a var.
i.e. `velLine:Line = new Line()` should be `velLine = new Line()`